# How to optimise a[i] = -b[i] * (c[i] + d);

Tags: c, loops, optimization

Just wondering, given the code below, is there a better way of writing this to improve performance?

```
int i, N;
double a[], b[], c[], d;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    a[i] = -b[i] * (c[i] + d);
}
```

Comment: Optimize? What is not optimal about it? And your code is syntactically invalid.

Comment: Please wrap this into a [mcve] to allow pointing out the problems it has BEFORE optimisation. Then, for optimisation of a working code, prefer the codereviewers.

Comment: this is the right job for CUDA and OpenCL. With the GPU you can gain in performance (execution time).

Answer (score 4):

As written, your code doesn't show the correct declarations of `a`, `b`, and `c`. If they're actually pointers (including function arguments declared like arrays) or arrays in pointed-to structs, be sure you make the pointers `restrict` qualified if possible. This will make it so a decent compiler can vectorize your loop.

You can see the effects of `restrict` (and what happens if you remove it) in the example code linked from P__J__'s answer. Without it, the compiler cannot assume `a` doesn't point to memory overlapping with what `b` or `c` points to, so it can't load `b[i+1]` or `c[i+1]` until `a[i]` is stored. This completely precludes loading them in parallel, i.e. essentially precludes vectorization.

Otherwise, no, your loop is optimal.

Comment: You might add a short explanation for the effect of `restrict`.

Answer (score 3):

Compiler are quite good in the optimizing such a stuff

https://godbolt.org/z/Q8sWqp